# Compare Numerical Days of the Year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

I'm working on a SQL stored procedure where I need to determine whether or not a date stored in a table is greater than or equal to fifteen days after the current date.

The first thing I came up with was to use the following in my WHERE clause:

```
DAY(GETDATE()) <= DAY(tableName.dateValue) - 15
```

However, I believe this only compares days of each date's specific month. I want to compare numerical days of the year. I'd like to be able to determine that, for example, the date in the table is the 200th day of the year and today, the 180th day of the year, is more than fifteen days before that.

Is there a way to accomplish this with GETDATE()? Do I need to use Julian dates, or anything like that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is the logic you need: `WHERE tableName.dateValue >= DATEADD(DAY, 15, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));` - as a bonus, it will be sargable. You may need to use 16 instead of 15 depending on what exactly you mean by "fifteen days after"...

Comment: @AaronBertrand in your query you should add -15 days, not +15days

Comment: @SQL.injection disagree. OP states: `a date stored in a table is greater than or equal to fifteen days after the current date.`

Comment: @AaronBertrand ach so, I read the question too fast. Didn't realized the dates were in the future.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Which would perform better `DATEADD(DAY, 15, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))` or `cast(getdate()+15 as date)` ?

Comment: If you use a so-called Julian day then you'll still have the same problem you had with `DAY()`. Eventually it's going to roll over to a new year, it just won't happen as frequently.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Your method is just what I was looking for. If you care to post it again as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Please [don't use GETDATE()+15](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) - and it has nothing to do with performance. If you're worried about performance, make sure there is a covering index on the datetime column to support this query, and stop worrying about minuscule things like the expression used to derive a runtime constant.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DATEDIFF()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, tableName.dateValue, GETDATE()) >= 15 ;
```

But for the query to be sargable, the condition should not be doing any calculations on the column:

```
WHERE tableName.dateValue >= DATEADD(day, 15, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) ;
```

Comment: Bad for two reasons: (1) [shorthand like `dd` is lazy and error-prone](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) (2) this is not sargable - even if an index exists on `dateValue`, this query will still have to scan the entire table.

Comment: @Abbath, you can always edit your answers - especially when someone comments with a mistake or an omission you made.

Comment: @ypercube thanks for the edit, but I was not even aware of what 'sargable' was and did not feel 100% comfortable putting it in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, table.dateValue, getdate())
```

will give you the number of days between the current date and another date.

WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, table.dateValue, getdate()) >= -15

Should provide you with your answer.

Answer (score -3):

You should use Datediff https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189794.aspx

Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.
for example

```
 select DATEDIFF(DAY,getDATE(),tableName.dateValue)
```

would return the diference in days between the actual date and your stored one

```
select   * from 
tableName 
where DATEDIFF(DAY,getDATE(),tableName.dateValue) >= 15
```

This could be slow in a large table so you would rather use Aaron Bertrand comment/answer

Comment: Not really, comparing today (say, February 26th, 2015) to the day of the month of whatever the date is in the table (if that date is March 14, 2015, then you're saying DATEDIFF(DAY, today, 14) which is DATEDIFF(DAY, today, 1900-01-15).

Comment: @AaronBertrand from what i get he has the date stored and is comparing using the day() function to get the day part

Comment: @Smog try your code out. It doesn't work. He wants to get all the rows where the stored date is >= 15 days after today. Stop thinking about what his code currently says.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the feedback fixed,  i think you should make your comment an answer :)